# How to combine different routes for Http().bindAndHandle?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

My application structure looks like

```
com.app.service/
                EmailService.scala
                MonitorStatusService.scala
Server.scala
```

**EmailService.scala**

```
trait EmailService extends EmailProtocols {
  implicit val materializer: Materializer
  private val ecStatusResponse = ECStatus("ok", "Welcome to Server")

  val emailRoutes =
    logRequestResult("email-service") {
      pathPrefix("ec") {
        (post & entity(as[ECFailure])) { ecFailure =>
          complete {
            Postman.send(TenantFailure(ecFailure.symbolicName) getMessage)
            "OK"
          }
        }
      } ~
        path("") {
          get {
            complete {
              ecStatusResponse
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**MonitorStatusService.scala**

```
trait MonitorStatusService extends EmailProtocols {
  implicit val materializer: Materializer
  private val ecStatusResponse = ECStatus("ok", "Welcome to Monitor Service")

  val monitorRoutes =
    logRequestResult("monitor-service") {
      pathPrefix("monitor") {
        (post & entity(as[ECFailure])) { ecFailure =>
          complete {
            Postman.send(TenantFailure(ecFailure.symbolicName) getMessage)
            "OK"
          }
        }
      } ~
        path("") {
          get {
            complete {
              ecStatusResponse
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server.scala**

```
object Server extends App
with EmailService
with MonitorStatusService {
  var config: Option[Config] = None
  if (args.length > 0) {
    config = Some(ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(args(0) trim)))
    println(config)
  }

  val host = if (config.isDefined) config.get.getString("server.host").toString else "localhost"
  val port = if (config.isDefined) config.get.getString("server.port").toInt else 8080

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("server")
  val executor = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  println(s"Starting server on ($host, $port)")
  Http().bindAndHandle(emailRoutes, host, port)
}
```

**What I need?**
I want to bind multiple routes like

```
Http().bindAndHandle(emailRoutes + monitorRoutes, host, port)
```

But when I do that I see error as

[image]

What shall I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same way as you combined routes under both object using `~`.
So change `+` to `~`.

Did not check this though but this is how it used to work under spray so it should here.